# How to verify a soft link in svn without checkout?

Tags: svn

I want to verify the correctness of a soft link in svn. But I don't want to checkout. Is there any method? I try "svn ls", but it cannot give information about soft link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `svn proplist` to make sure the file has the `svn:special` property set.

`svn cat` will give you the file it points to.

See the [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.7) for more information.